# Symfony2 Forms: create new or select existing

Tags: forms, symfony

I have and entity A which relates oneToMany with entity B.
I want the user to have the option of selecting from existing B entities or create a new one on the form of type A. So far I have this on my form:

```
->add('ExistingB', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\B',
            'required'    => false,
            'property_path' => 'B',
            'mapped' => false,
        ))

 ->add('newB',  new BType(), array(
            'required'    => false,
            'property_path' => 'B',
            'mapped' => false,
        ));

 $builder->addEventListener(
     FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT , function (FormEvent $event) {
          $formB= $event->getForm()->get('newB');

         if ($formB->get('name')->getData() != null){
                 //here I need to somehow say to the form that it needs to set mapped true 
                //to the formB field so it can create a new entity and update the relationship
         }else{
                  //here I need to do the same but with the ExistingB field
                }
         }
    );`
```

I cant find how to change the mapped attribute, and the times I got it, it doesn't create the entity. I suppose that's because in the post_submit event its too late for changes on the fields since the data is already downloaded to the A entity.

But.. if I use the pre_submit event, then I can't get the data of the child formB, since it always gives me null when I ask for it.

So... where is my big mistake?
Somebody can show me another way to deal with new or existing feature in symfony2 forms. I really can't believe that it could be that hard to implement so common behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use pre submit event, you just have to do this like this:
https://github.com/LPodolski/selectOrCreateOptionForm/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Form/ItemType.php#L36

full project that demonstrates how this should work: https://github.com/LPodolski/selectOrCreateOptionForm

Comment: Hey man I dont know how to say it, but thank you indeed very much. I never expect a full working solution. This is just the greatest. 
As far as I understand it, you just need to remove the unbound new field and added again with the property path correctly setted. But I have a very small question out of curiosity, how is that Symfony knows it will bound this field to my entity and prevent using the one defined under 
    ->add('itemOption', null, array('property'    => 'name',         'empty_value' => 'create new itemOption', ))

Anyway it works smooth as heaven so thank you again =)

Comment: @AlbertoPadilla itemOptionNew is bound only if select is not empty it is checked by empty functions https://github.com/LPodolski/selectOrCreateOptionForm/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Form/ItemType.php#L40

2. I think symfony just applies fields binding from oldest to newest so newest is always bound to entity but really not checked this in that much of detail

Comment: I am having a problem my friend with this aproach. If I load an entity tipe A wich already has a entity type B linked to it and I decide to create a new one, then what I get is an update of the existing B instead of creating a new one. Is there an easy way to deal with this?

Comment: solved! I just needed to add a line seting the relation to null on the presubmit event

Comment: Hi, what did you put on your line to set the relation to null ? I tried $data['itemOption'] = null; but it did not work...

Comment: I too am struggling to 'set the relation to null' to prevent the previous setting from being updated when I want to create a new one. How do I set the relation null?