# Is this the right way to generate a form from multiple (partial) FormTypes in Symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony, optimization, doctrine, entity

I'm struggling to get my head around nested formtypes in Symfony/Doctrine. I want to be able to generate forms with the following components as an example, where the user can create a new <kbd>Product</kbd> at the same time as making any potential updates to <kbd>Category</kbd> object with further information if required:

- Product Description (text: from `ProductType`)
- Category (dropdown: generated from `CategoryType`)
- Category Storage Location (text: further information to add to Category)

`ProductType.php` **contains just a subset of the attributes** of the entity <kbd>Product</kbd>.

`CategoryType.php` **contains just a subset of the attributes** of the entity <kbd>Category</kbd>.

## In controller:

```
public function newProductAction(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Products();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('saved_updated');
    }
}
```

## In ProductType:

Apologies for the pseudo-code here - the two things I'm most confused about here are:

- Should it be referencing the <kbd>Category</kbd> object or `CategoryType`?
- `->add('category_location',new CategoryType(), $category)`...or whatever needs to be done here...

  ```
  class ProductType extends AbstractType
  {
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {    
      $builder->add('productname')
              ->add('category','entity,'array(
                    'class=>'AppBundle:Category',
                    'choice_label'=>'category_name',
                    'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
                     return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                               ->orderBy('c.category_name','ASC');
                    }))
               ->add('category_location',new CategoryType(), $category)
               ->getForm();
      }

      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
      {
          $resolver->setDefaults(array(
              'data_class'=>'\AppBundle\Entity\Products'
          ));
      }

      public function getName()
      {
          return 'product';
      }
  }
  ```

## In CategoryType:

The form I'm trying to create here doesn't need it but how about if `CategoryType` was called directly in another form?

```
    class CategoryType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {    
        $builder->add('category_name')
                ->add('category_location')
                ->getForm();
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class'=>'\AppBundle\Entity\Categorys'
            ));
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'category';
        }
    }
```

Comment: After some modifications, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923701/synfony2-forms-create-new-or-select-existing) solution works for me.